# QMenu context menu initial size too small and w/o content in QtOpenGL.QGLWidget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, contextmenu, qglwidget

I am using `PyQt 4.8.6` bindings for `Python 2.7.9`. I would like to create a context menu inside `QtOpenGL.QGLWidget`:

```
class OpenGLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        #    context menu properties
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.popMenu = QtGui.QMenu(parent=self)
        print self.popMenu.sizeHint()
        print self.popMenu.size()
        self.popMenu.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.popMenu.setFixedHeight(100)
        print self.popMenu.size()
        self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('Refresh', self.updateGL()))
        self.popMenu.addSeparator()
        self.popMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction('test2', None))
        self.popMenu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last_pos = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.contextMenuEvent(event)
```

It prints out:

```
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(2, 2)
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(100, 30)
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(100, 100)
```

And the context menu looks empty, like below:

[image: Empty context menu]

I would like to know how to set context menu size to be adjustable and also seen from initial settings? Do you have any ideas why there is no menu text (function) inside? I also use a context menu in tree view and there it works OK, but here I have a problem. And if I dons set fixed menu size, the menu is smaller than the letters of the coordinate system axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a way for defining actions was not quite OK, although I found it in an example somewhere. The context menu items (actions) should be defined as:

```
_updateGLAction = popMenu.addAction("Refresh")
_updateGLAction.triggered.connect(self.repaintGL)
```